# How to compare two comma separated list in SQL Server and return the values in the list that both have in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question above is all I need help with.
I have two common separated lists and I need to compare the two lists and return the values that are in both lists.

Comment: Normalize the data properly, then just use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Agree with @David.  I take it you have a list of values in a single field, in your SQL database.  That is not proper normalized form.  You need to put the values in a separate table.  Once you have a properly normalized db, then you can expect SQL to do the comparison for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for instance, [parse each list into a table (variable)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx) and then use an inner join to obtain the common values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split` function from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) and then get the common elements using `INTERSECT`:

```
DECLARE @String1 VARCHAR(50)='A,B,C'
DECLARE @String2 VARCHAR(50)='A,B'

SELECT  * FROM dbo.Split(@String1, ',')
INTERSECT
SELECT  * FROM dbo.Split(@String2, ',')
```

I am referring to this Split function as originally posted by Romil Kumar Jain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns).

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
      @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
      @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

      DECLARE @Item                 VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
GO
```

Comment: The strings have already been created and are stored in a variable... How would you then manipulate the code to solve the problem.

Comment: Updated post, strings are now stored in variables called `@String1` and `@String2`

Comment: All I could find on this website was how to return true, false, 1 or 0 if values matched... Not the actual values themselves.